# MIPS Assembly Code to Count The Number of Digits in a String

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, mars-simulator

I am writing a MIPS Assembly code to count the number of digits in a string. For Example, if the user string was: "qapww9...$$$64"
The output would be 3.

I used ascii codes to set the boundary of integers (48 for 0, 57 for 9). I wanted to check through each character if is greater than or equal to 0, then less than or equal to 9, if yes then add one to the counter, then move to the next character. My code is failing off after typing my string input

*EDITS*
: I am receiving feedback that I am not properly incrementing through each character of the string properly. What I am doing currently is `addi $t0, $t0, 1`.

```
# MIPS assembly language program to count the number of decimal digits in an ascii string of characters.
# $a0 = $t0 = user input
# $t1 = counter
# $t2 = temporary register to hold each byte value
.data
    length: .space 100
    p: .asciiz "\nEnter a string: "
    p2: .asciiz "\nNumber of integers: "
.text

#Prompt User for String
   la $a0, p                   #print prompt
   li $v0, 4                #load string stored in v0
   syscall                  #display prompt string

#Get user input
   li $v0, 8                #load string stored in v0
   la $a0, length              #set string length to 100
   addi $a1, $0, 100           #add length 100 to regist $a1
   syscall

   move $t0, $a0                #user input is now in register $t0
   addi $t1, $0, 0              #initialize counter

#loop to check if greater or equal to 0
lowerBound:
   lb $t2, 0($t0)           #load first character of user input into $t2
   bge $t2, 48, upperBound     #branch to upperBound checker if char is greater than or equal 0
   addi $t0, $t0, 1         #increment to next character in string
   beqz $t0, end            #if character = 0 (end of string), end
   j lowerBound

#loop to check if less than or equal to 9
upperBound:
    ble  $t2, 57, count_digits  #if in the range 0-9, just to count digits and add 1 to counter
    j lowerBound            #loop through again

count_digits:
    addi $t1, $t1, 1           #add 1 to counter
    j lowerBound

end:
    li $v0, 4          #load string print service
    la $a0, p2         #load address of prompt 2 inro $a0
    syscall            #print prompt
    la $a0, ($t1)          #load address of count into $a0
    li $v0, 1          #specify print integer service
    syscall            #print count
```

Comment: You are loading the same character over and over. Your counter is not `$t2` and how exactly do you intend to get to `end`?

Comment: @Jester how so? Where am I going wrong where I am not incrementing each character in the string to check. I plan to get to end using the line: beqz $t2, end     ... I believe this means if the character of $t2 = 0, then that means the string is empty, therefore I am done checking.

Comment: `lb $t2, 0($t0) ` is loading from `$t0` and `$t0` never changes. Also if the character is less than 48 you just keep looping in the `lowerBound` block, you never exit.

Comment: ```addi  $t2, $t2, 1``` doesnt this move to the next character? Then it loops through ```lowerBound``` again to check the next one?

Comment: Why would incrementing `$t2` do anything useful?

Comment: @Jester my knowledge is that by ```lb $t2 0($t0)``` the first character of the user string is now in ```$t2``` , then I can check if it is between 0-9 using my branch instructions. after these instructions are executed, I could do ```addi $t2, $t2, 1``` , meaning this would move to the next character to check. I add 1 to the counter every time a character is in the 0-9 range. I would do this until the string is empty ( I think this would be ```beqz $t2, end``` ) . Then I could print the counter number. How else would I check each character if I didn't increment ```$t2```?

Comment: `$t2` is the character you loaded. It's pointless to increment it. You want to increment `$t0` so you can use that to load the next character into `$t2`.

Comment: Ok, ive modified it so that ```$t0``` is being incremented instead of ```$t2``` , however the same issue is occurring.

Comment: The `beqz` should still reference `$t2` because you want to check if the character was zero. Also the continuation jumps from the `upperBound` and `count_digits` should go back to the increment otherwise those cases would not move to the next character. PS: learn to use your simulator to single step the code to see what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

You stuck in an endless loop when the character ASCII is greater then 57. Because in this case you will jump to `upperBound` where you jump back to `lowerBound` endlessly since the pointer to the string ($t0) will not incremented in this case. Just move the increment part above the `bge` so it will execute always.

Also you try to print the count address for some unknown reason not the value as you should.

The modified code

```
# MIPS assembly language program to count the number of decimal digits in an ascii string of characters.
# $a0 = $t0 = user input
# $t1 = counter
# $t2 = temporary register to hold each byte value
.data
    length: .space 100
    p: .asciiz "\nEnter a string: "
    p2: .asciiz "\nNumber of integers: "
.text

#Prompt User for String
   la $a0, p                   #print prompt
   li $v0, 4                #load string stored in v0
   syscall                  #display prompt string

#Get user input
   li $v0, 8                #load string stored in v0
   la $a0, length              #set string length to 100
   addi $a1, $0, 100           #add length 100 to regist $a1
   syscall

   move $t0, $a0                #user input is now in register $t0
   addi $t1, $0, 0              #initialize counter

#loop to check if greater or equal to 0
lowerBound:
   lb $t2, 0($t0)           #load first character of user input into $t2
   addi $t0, $t0, 1         #increment to next character in string
   bge $t2, 48, upperBound     #branch to upperBound checker if char is greater than or equal 0
   beqz $t2, end            #if character = 0 (end of string), end
   j lowerBound

#loop to check if less than or equal to 9
upperBound:
    ble  $t2, 57, count_digits  #if in the range 0-9, just to count digits and add 1 to counter
    j lowerBound            #loop through again

count_digits:
    addi $t1, $t1, 1           #add 1 to counter
    j lowerBound

end:
    li $v0, 4          #load string print service
    la $a0, p2         #load address of prompt 2 inro $a0
    syscall            #print prompt
    move $a0, $t1          #load count into $a0
    li $v0, 1          #specify print integer service
    syscall            #print count
```